# Service closes when I clear app History by Long Pressing Home key

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am Launching service From Activity. Then Service runs a countdown timer to launch ads.

But when Someone clears my apps History by Long Pressing Home key it force stop the app at the line where I am checking Intent extras.

It gives NULL Pointer Exception at that line as below,

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  

if (intent.getExtras() != null && intent.hasExtra("type")) // <== NPE at this line 
        type = intent.getExtras().getString("type");
.
.
.
}
```

As you can see I even tried to check if Intent is null `intent.getExtras() != null` but it still gives NPE and Force closes app.

Why `onStartCommand` is called when I clear history and countdown timer Finishes and launch other activity, which launches another service Afterwards.

LogCat is :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.main.example.AdService with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
        06-23 13:58:05.004: E/AndroidRuntime(12667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2660)
        06-23 13:58:05.004: E/AndroidRuntime(12667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:149)
        06-23 13:58:05.004: E/AndroidRuntime(12667):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402)
        06-23 13:58:05.004: E/AndroidRuntime(12667):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        06-23 13:58:05.004: E/AndroidRuntime(12667):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
        06-23 13:58:05.004: E/AndroidRuntime(12667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000)
        06-23 13:58:05.004: E/AndroidRuntime(12667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        06-23 13:58:05.004: E/AndroidRuntime(12667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        06-23 13:58:05.004: E/AndroidRuntime(12667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
        06-23 13:58:05.004: E/AndroidRuntime(12667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
        06-23 13:58:05.004: E/AndroidRuntime(12667):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        06-23 13:58:05.004: E/AndroidRuntime(12667): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        06-23 13:58:05.004: E/AndroidRuntime(6295): com.main.example.AdService.onStartCommand(AdService.java:83)
        06-23 13:58:05.004: E/AndroidRuntime(12667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2643)
```

Comment: have you returned START_STICKY from onStartCommand() ?

Comment: no! If I use START_STICKY then `onStartCommand` won't be called if someone clears app from history ?

Comment: It'll make sure that the service is not closed until you explicitly do so. Might Work.

Comment: one thing I noticed that service is shown running in settings, but `onStartCommand` is called and it shows NPE at Intent.getExtra line

Comment: does the onDestroy method of the activity have anything that might start the service again ?

Comment: you mean onDestroy of service , I am calling AsyncTask  to inform webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Intent` itself is `null`. This is expected behavior for `START_STICKY`, when Android restarts your service, as is noted in [the documentation for `START_STICKY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY).

Comment: is it an expected behaviour though ? The call to onStartCommand() ?

Comment: I didn't used START_STICKY . it is `return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);`

Comment: @D_Vaibhav: The default return value from `onStartCommand()` is `START_STICKY`. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Service.java (line 449-452 in current edition of the source).

Comment: @ShivamVerma: Yes, because the default return value from `onStartCommand()` is `START_STICKY`.

Comment: can I use `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` documentation says that The service will not receive a onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) call with a null Intent`

Comment: @D_Vaibhav: Only do that if you are marking commands as being completed, using `stopSelf(int)`. If you are not, either be in position to ignore the `null` `Intent`, or use `START_NOT_STICKY` so your service remains stopped.

Comment: Yeah will think on that .. Thanks